# Play 2.1 upgrade logs controller is not the right type

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

After upgraded to Play 2.1, there are few log messages when application starts. What does it mean?

```
[debug] application - class controllers.WebProfile is not the right type
[debug] application - class controllers.WebProfile is not the right type
[debug] application - class controllers.WebProfile is not the right type
[debug] application - class controllers.WebDemo is not the right type
[debug] application - class controllers.WebDemo is not the right type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use swagger in your project?

If so, your controller don't have api annotation.

Look at  : https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-play2/app/play/modules/swagger/ApiHelpInventory.scala#L210